# $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\overline {A}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

-Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\overline {A}$

*Recall.* $\overline {A}=A\cup A'$. $\overline {A}$ is called closure of $A$.

**My question is**: If I prove ''A is closed iff it contains all limit points'', then would I prove $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\overline {A}$?

Comment: You know that $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed that contains $A$?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use the definition of my foreposter, you can use what you stated, since: assume $A$ is closed and $A \neq \overline{A}$. Then with the definition of $A'$ you will come to the conclusion that there has to be a limit in $\overline{A}$ that is not in $A$, what is a contradiction to your proposition. The other way is trivial then.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of "closed". For example, in Pugh's text the definition of "closed" is: $A$ is closed if it contains all its limit points. If your definition is: $A$ is closed if $A = \overline{A} = A \cup A'$, then you need to show $A$ contains its *cluster points*. So the question you have to answer is: how are cluster points related to limit points?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your definition of closed set is the set which contains all its limit points.

$\impliedby$ Suppose $A=\bar A$, then $A=A\cup A'$, so any point $x\in \bar A\implies x\in A$, so that $A$ contains all its limit points and is hence closed.

$\implies$ Suppose now that $A$ is closed. Then by definition, it contains all its limit points. Now $A\subseteq\bar A$. Let $x\in \bar A$. Then either $x\in A$ or $x\in A'$. If the former then we are done. If $x\in A'$, then $x\in A$ since $A$ is closed. So $\bar A\subseteq A$ and hence $A=\bar A$.